# Trying to decide if a golf cart will fit under a tunnel

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

I just wanted to check my work on this one to make sure Im doing it right.

Suppose we have an overpass described by the points (0,0), ( 3,0) for the start and end of the parbola, and (1.5, 2.5) for the position of the arch.

now suppose we want to see can we fit a golf buggy of dimensions 1.8 m height by 1.4 m width.

first of all I found the function :

$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ in general

so

$f(0)=c=0$

$f(3)=9a+3b=0$

or $3a +b=0$

$f(1.25)=2.25a+1.25b=2.5$

or $9a+6b=10$

doing a simulateous I got $b=10/3$ and $a=-10/9$

the next thing I did was find the roots at the point where the height of the tunnel is 1.8 and I wanted to investigate is the distance between them greater than 1.4

When I used the -b formula on

$f(x)=\tfrac{-10x^2}{9}+\tfrac{10x}{3}-1.8$

I got $x=2.29$ and $x=0.706$

this gives a width of 1.53 which is greater than the neccesary width of 1.4.

Does that look correct to you guys ?